# resetting unity theme doesn't stick

Tags: unity, themes

Ubuntu 14.04
I have Ambiance theme applied, but font colors are not following the theme.
Font colors are black, which is very hard to read on the dark background.
For example, the font in the switch user/logout menu, or the font colors in the application menu.

I have tried

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

and this changes the font colors.
But when I logout and login again, I'm back to the black text.[image: This is a screen shot,look at the top right to see an example]

Comment: I solved the problem. I think that moving the folders gtk-2.0 and gtk-3.0 out of ~/.config helped. Probably only one of those folders is responsible. I then did the two commands above. The reset of the theme was then persistent.